# Open Text Messaging App via button click

Tags: java, android

I am sorry if this is a duplicated question and all but I am trying to get a button click event to open a text messaging app and populated the sms number with this number "12345" (its not a text number but I am using it for an example.

Here is my intent code:

```
    View.OnClickListener texthandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // implements your things
        //TODO: change number
        String textnum = "12345";
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:" + textnum));
    }
};
```

Once I press/click the button nothing happens. If someone could help me to fix this it would be great, thanks

Comment: after you create the intent do startActivity(smsIntent);

Comment: Cheers @jasonwarford :) #sillyme ha